# Bind fancy box to elements not yet loaded

Tags: jquery, asp.net, fancybox

I am using datatables (paginator) to display records.  I have an
option with each record, each of which are to open a fancy box model
window.  It works fine for the elements loaded on the first page, but
for elements that are on subsequent pages (not visible when page is
first rendered), fancy box is not binding to them.

Ho can i get this to work?
Thanks

See below:

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
     $("[id$=mdialog]").fancybox({
         'width': '75%',
         'height': '80%',
         'autoScale': false,
         'transitionIn': 'none',
         'transitionOut': 'none',
         'type': 'iframe'
     });


 });




  <td><a id="mdialog" href="details.aspx?scode=<%# Eval("SCode")%>">[..]</a></td>
```

Comment: try with class selector.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use jQuery's [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function to bind the listener to an element that doesn't exist yet.

Then attach it to the object's onload event, and apply your current transformations to it.